# Having problems with iguanatex

Tags: powerpoint

I'm trying to type an equation and this is what I have input,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \dot \textbf{w}. \nabla_6 f = 0$

\end{document}
```

However it is not working and I am unsure on the causes.

Comment: It should be `\dot{\mathbf{w}}`. Probably also `\cdot` instead of `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Observe that I wrote `\nabla_{\!6}` -- this "snugs up" the digit `6` to the `\nabla` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \dot{\mathbf{w}}\cdot \nabla_{\!6} f = 0$
\end{document}
```